# exporting a html page to msword by below code but it's not exporting the image

Tags: php, html

this the html page look like which is with out any error.

```
<html>
<body>
<table border='1'>
<tr><td><img src='logo.png' width="100px" height="100px" ></td></tr>
<tr><td>adfadfasdfasdfasf</td></tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

here it looks fine and shows the image but when I want to export it to ms-word by:

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-word"); 
header("Expires: 0"); 
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0"); 
header("content-disposition: attachment;filename=WeeklyBulletin.doc");
?>
   <html>
<body>
<table border='1'>
<tr><td><img src='logo.png' width="100px" height="100px" ></td></tr>
<tr><td>adfadfasdfasdfasf</td></tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

it is not exporting the image but only the text and table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the document is opened in MS Word, the relative img link `logo.png` won't be loaded as the path makes no sense in the context of a Word document. If you update the `src` to the full path of the image (including `http://YOURDOMAIN.COM/` etc) then Word will load the image.

This will allow the image to be seen by anyone viewing the doc with an internet connection active. However, if you're looking to embed the image in to the Word doc, you'll likely need to look at something a bit more complex. Something like [PHPWord](http://phpword.codeplex.com/) may be a better fit for your needs.